# Websocket connection running on port other than 80 are blocked in corporate network

Tags: javascript, html, websocket, network-programming, network-security

i am using websocket based webgl application running on 15000 port but the problem is when some one try to access the application from corporate network ,he wouldnt able to get the data using websocket.

How to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Many solutions:

1) Ask the network administrator to open a specific port and use this new unlocked port (if it's for the job, maybe it's possible. I did that many times and for me, it was always a success, don't forget to clearly explain for what/who it is).

2) Ask the network administrator to create a NAT route (a link here : [NAT explained by CISCO](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/network-address-translation-nat/26704-nat-faq-00.html). For example, redirect the public port number 15000 to the "private" (server's port) port number *n*. Same success rate as above imho.

3) Use the port 80 if you can't do another way... Depending of your dev server, it can be easy. For example you can build a webservice using the port 80 with NodeJS and Express, it's simple as pie and very effective.